# List iterator erase "Debug assertion failed"

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have 2 std::lists. I want to delete all the items from list 1 and insert it in the 2nd and vice versa. My code is not working (getting access violation and "list iterator not dereferencable")

```
for ( std::list<Item *>::iterator it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); ++it ) {
        it = list1.erase( it ); 
        list2.push_back( *it ); 
    }
it = list1.begin();
it = list2.erase( it ); // because the last element is not deleted in the above loop
list2.push_back( *it );
```

Symmetrical code for the 2nd method. I manage to transfer the items between the 2 lists one time, but the next I get the error.

Any help?

Comment: `std::swap(list1, list2)`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb the `std::list::swap` member function is guaranteed to be constant time. It should only involve swapping two pointers (and probably a size data member in C++11).

Comment: @juanchopanza: That would certainly be better. The `std::swap` function would still perform better than the presented implementation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily and efficiently done with `std::list`'s [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/swap) member function:

```
list1.swap(list2);
```

This has constant time complexity.

Comment: Easily the fastest and best answer I ever got.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to use `list::swap`.
But your code show you have some misunderstanding.

```
for ( std::list<Item *>::iterator it = list1.begin(); it != list1.end(); ++it ) {
   it = list1.erase( it ); // this effectively erase and destroy *it, 
                 // and erase() return an iterator to the NEXT element. 
                 // Now it=it+1
   list2.push_back( *it ); // you copy the NEXT element!!  
   // here is where we efectively get the ++it of the 'for'. 
   // When erase was used when ‘it’ was at end()-1, erase return end()
   // The attempt to do it=end()+1 is an error probably detected by an assertion. 
}
```

If `list1` have originally even number of elements, for example 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 the iterator `end()` will point to the inexistent 10, with you don’t need (cant) erase. This ‘`for`’ will delete the even elements (0,2,4,6,8) , and copy to `list2` the odd (1,3,5,7,9). But if originally `list1` have odd elements, for example 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 the last deleted is 8, `erase` return an iterator to the inexistent 9 = `end(),` and the ‘for’ make an attempt to increment it with don’t pass the assertion.